# Authentication factors and their presentation

Tags: security, authentication, factors

A multiple factor authentication system (software or others) requires an entity to produce data in support of multiple factors of authentication. Generally these factors are:

1. Something you have e.g. debit card.
2. Something you know e.g. PIN
3. Something you are e.g. biometrics

These factors can uniquely establish the authenticity of an entity to a system. However the system is blind to the entity itself that produces the data in support of the factors. For example, cards can be forged, phone receiving an OTP can be stolen, biometrics can be stolen (finger and iris vein  seem to be resistant though).

Therefore, would it be true to say that an authentication system can *only infer* that an entity is what it is based on data provided?

Comment: ... and your programming question is?

Comment: None. Mainly because, I wanted to understand the opinion about this topic. For example, all programming related to factors seem to be around factors presented than presenter.